# Array2d java errors

Tags: java, arrays

My source code:

```
 public class My {
    public void Array(int[][] numbers) {
        for(int r=0;r<numbers.length;r++){
            for(int c=0;c<numbers[0].length-1;c++){
                if(numbers[r][c+1]>numbers[r][c]){
                    numbers[r][c]=numbers[r][c+1];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    int[][] numbers = {{3,4,5,6},{4,5,6,7},{5,6,7,8}};
    Array(numbers);
}
```

Errors:

```
/My.java:13: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    Array(numbers);
    ^
/My.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
    Array(numbers);
                 ^
2 errors
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You can't have statements dangling around in a class, wrap it around a method.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @polko When do you expect the last two lines of code to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have instructions outside methods.

This is a way to fix your issue (note the `static` keyword):

```
public class My {
    public static void Array(int[][] numbers) {
        for(int r=0;r<numbers.length;r++){
            for(int c=0;c<numbers[0].length-1;c++){
                if(numbers[r][c+1]>numbers[r][c]){
                    numbers[r][c]=numbers[r][c+1];
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static final void Main(String[] agrs) {
        int[][] numbers = {{3,4,5,6},{4,5,6,7},{5,6,7,8}};
        Array(numbers);
    }
}
```